# Как отправлять сообщение от бота, и через время удалять

Tags: aiogram

```
import aiogram
import time
import string, json
@dp.message_handler()
async def all_messages:
    if {i.lower().translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)) for i in message.text.split(' ')}\
            .intersection(set(json.load(open('cenz.json'))))!=set():
            await message.delete()
            l=await message.answer('маты запрещены')
            time.sleep(2.0)
            await l.delete()
```

Так не получается

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio

msg=await message.answer('маты запрещены')
asyncio.sleep(2)
await msg.delete()
```